# SQLite Database Problem while delete

Tags: android, sqlite

Hi to All I am new to Android.
I am using SQLite DataBase in my Application 
meanwhile I am Written Queries using +
Like delete from tablename where value = + value;

this is my query

```
String delete_query = "delete from " + tableName
                    + " where title = '" + title + "'";
            database.execSQL(delete_query);
```

I want to write this Query using placeholder ?.
so that i tried

```
database.delete(tableName,  title + "?" , new String[] {title});
```

instead "?" i tried (?)/('?')/'?'
but it is giving me an error....

can any one tell me how to write appropriate query using ?.....

Thanks in Advance.
Mahaveer

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have put the **equal** sign:-

```
database.delete(tableName, title + "=?" , new String[] {title});
```

Comment: hey can u provide me any useful information for creating table and also for insert  & select from it?? will be thankful to you... i have added my code in same post... thanks

Comment: @Mahaveer SQLiteDatabase has methods for CRUD operations.

Answer (score 1):

As far as possible, try to use the less raw queries you can. Two advantages:

- Query parameters will be escaped by the system (protection against SQL injection)
- The code will be more readable

See the [delete](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#delete%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) function of SQLiteDatabase class

> public int delete (String table, String whereClause, String[]
>   whereArgs)
>
> Convenience method for deleting rows in the
>   database.
>
> **table** the table to delete from
>
> **whereClause**   the optional WHERE clause
>   to apply when deleting. Passing null will delete all rows.
>
> Returns the number of rows affected if a whereClause is passed in, 0
>   otherwise. To remove all rows and get a count pass "1" as the
>   whereClause.

In your case:

```
final String where = "title=?";
final String[] args = new String[] { title };
database.delete(tableName, where, args);
```

Comment: Thanks MarvinLabs it Works m very Thankful to you for help.

Comment: Hey Marvin Sorry to disturb you again but can you provide me some useful tips for create table, insert into table & also for select queries...?? thanks

Comment: this is my code for insert. String insert_query = "INSERT INTO " + tableName + " VALUES "+ "('" + title + "', '" + url + "')";
database.execSQL(insert_query);

Comment: All you need is there: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html and if not enough, google for SQLite android tutorial

Comment: and this is for creating a table..  String create_query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + tableName+ "(title VARCHAR, urlname VARCHAR);";
sampleDB.execSQL(create_query);